# Listing model coefficients in descending order

Tags: r

I have a dataset with both continuous and categorical variables. I am running regression to predict one of the variables based on the other variables in the dataset. After comparing the results of ridge, lasso and elastic-net regression, the lasso regression is the best model to proceed with.

I used the 'coef' function to extract the model's coefficients, however, the result is a very long list with over 800 variables (as some of my categorical variables have many levels). Is there a way I can quickly rank the coefficients from largest to smallest? This is a glmnet model output

Reproducible problem with example code:

```
# Libraries Needed
library(caret)
library(glmnet)
library(mlbench)
library(psych)

# Data
data("BostonHousing")
data <- BostonHousing
str(data)

# Data Partition
set.seed(222)
ind <- sample(2, nrow(data), replace = T, prob = c(0.7, 0.3))
train <- data[ind==1,]
test <- data[ind==2,]

# Custom Control Parameters
custom <- trainControl(method = "repeatedcv",
                       number = 10,
                       repeats = 5,
                       verboseIter = T)

# Linear Model
set.seed(1234)
lm <- train(medv ~.,
            train,
            method='lm',
            trControl = custom)

# Results
lm$results
lm
summary(lm)
plot(lm$finalModel)

# Ridge Regression
set.seed(1234)
ridge <- train(medv ~.,
               train,
               method = 'glmnet',
               tuneGrid = expand.grid(alpha = 0,
                                      lambda = seq(0.0001, 1, length=5)),#try 5 values for lambda between 0.0001 and 1
                                      trControl=custom)
#increasing lambda = increasing penalty and vice versa
#increase lambda therefore will cause coefs to shrink

# Plot Results
plot(ridge)
plot(ridge$finalModel, xvar = "lambda", label = T)
plot(ridge$finalModel, xvar = 'dev', label=T)
plot(varImp(ridge, scale=T))

# Lasso Regression
set.seed(1234)
lasso <- train(medv ~.,
               train,
               method = 'glmnet',
               tuneGrid = expand.grid(alpha=1,
                                      lambda = seq(0.0001,1, length=5)),
               trControl = custom)

# Plot Results
plot(lasso)
lasso
plot(lasso$finalModel, xvar = 'lambda', label=T)
plot(lasso$finalModel, xvar = 'dev', label=T)
plot(varImp(lasso, scale=T))

# Elastic Net Regression
set.seed(1234)
en <- train(medv ~.,
            train,
            method = 'glmnet',
            tuneGrid = expand.grid(alpha = seq(0,1,length=10),
                                   lambda = seq(0.0001,1,length=5)),
            trControl = custom)

# Plot Results
plot(en)
plot(en$finalModel, xvar = 'lambda', label=T)
plot(en$finalModel, xvar = 'dev', label=T)
plot(varImp(en))

# Compare Models
model_list <- list(LinearModel = lm, Ridge = ridge, Lasso = lasso, ElasticNet=en)
res <- resamples(model_list)
summary(res)
bwplot(res)
xyplot(res, metric = 'RMSE')

# Best Model
en$bestTune
best <- en$finalModel
coef(best, s = en$bestTune$lambda)
```

Answer (score 0):

For most models all you'd have to do would be:

```
sort(coef(model), decreasing=TRUE)
```

Since you're using `glmnet` it's a little bit more complicated.  I'm going to replicate a **minimal** version of your example here (the other models, plots, etc. are *not necessary* in order for us to be able to reproduce your problem ...)

```
## Packages
library(caret)
library(glmnet)
library(mlbench) ## for BostonHousing data
# Data
data("BostonHousing")
data <- BostonHousing
# Data Partition
set.seed(222)
ind <- sample(2, nrow(data), replace = TRUE, prob = c(0.7, 0.3))
train <- data[ind==1,]
test <- data[ind==2,]
# Custom Control Parameters
custom <- trainControl(method = "repeatedcv",
                       number = 10,
                       repeats = 5,
                       verboseIter = TRUE)
# Elastic Net Regression
set.seed(1234)
en <- train(medv ~.,
            train,
            method = 'glmnet',
            tuneGrid = expand.grid(alpha = seq(0,1,length=10),
                                   lambda = seq(0.0001,1,length=5)),
            trControl = custom)
# Best Model
best <- en$finalModel
coefs <- coef(best, s = en$bestTune$lambda)
```

(This could probably be made simpler: for example, do you really need the custom control parameters to show us the example?  This would be even simpler without using `caret` - just using `glmnet - but I was afraid I might leave something out.)

Once you've got the coefficients, sorting does appear to work, albeit with a message about possible inefficiency:

```
sort(coefs, decreasing=TRUE)
## <sparse>[ <logic> ] : .M.sub.i.logical() maybe inefficient
##  [1]  25.191049410   5.078589706   1.389548822   0.244605193   0.045600250
##  [6]   0.008840485   0.004372752  -0.012701593  -0.028337745  -0.162794401
## [11]  -0.335062819  -0.901475516  -1.395091095 -12.632336419
```

`sort(as.numeric(coefs))` also appears to work fine.

If you want to sort the *entire matrix* (i.e. keeping the values for all penalization levels), you can take advantage of the fact that the penalization doesn't change the rank-order of the parameters:

```
coeftab <-coef(best)
lastvals <- coeftab[,ncol(coeftab)]
coeftab_s <- coeftab[order(lastvals,decreasing=TRUE),]
## plot, leaving out the intercept
matplot(t(coeftab_s)[,-1],type="l")
```

Comment: my coefficients are stored in a dgCMatrix so the above is not working for me:
[1] "dgCMatrix"
attr(,"package")
[1] "Matrix"

Comment: that's the kind of information you should show us in a [mcve] ... can you let us know at the very least what `str()` of your coefficients looks like?  (What package/code are you using that returns coefficients in this format?)

Comment: is this by any chance a `glmnet` model output? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47958170/coerce-model-coefficients-to-clean-2-column-dataframe

Comment: `str()` of coefficients (not able to showcase all with character cap):
'data.frame': 9203 obs. of  36 variables:
` $ Area_of_Origin                                               : Factor w/ 72 levels "11 - Lobby, Entranceway",..: 7 25 9 7 9 51 45 45 45 7 ...
 $ Building_Status                                              : Factor w/ 8 levels "","01 - Normal (no change)",..: 2 7 2 2 3 2 2 2 2 2 ...`

Yes, this is a glmnet model output. I am using lasso regression

Comment: Can you edit your question to include this?  Also, **please** tell us more about the modeling framework you're using.  (What you're describing here looks more like input data than coefficient output ...????)

Comment: I think I know how to answer this, but I'll wait for you to edit your question with more description [i.e. that you're using `glmnet`] and a [mcve].  (Hint: the very first example in `?glmnet` would make a fine, simple example in this case ...

Comment: Absolutely. I have a dataset with both continuous and categorical variables. I am running regression to predict one of the variables based on the other variables in the dataset. After comparing the results of ridge, lasso and elastic-net regression, the lasso regression is the best model to proceed with. I have now been able to obtain the coefficients but this list is very long because my categorical variables have so many levels

Comment: Please **edit your question to include this information**  (and the reproducible example) - thanks.

Comment: I've given this a shot. If this doesn't answer your question please edit your question to try to clarify (comments if necessary, but good question-edits are preferred ...)